# pod install giving errors on Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods

While running  pod install from the system on which jenkins is installed it is running fine but when we run the same command from jenkins it is giving following error. I have checked by adding and removing different pods to check if it is error with the particular pod but it is giving the same error.

````
```
   CocoaPods : 1.0.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
       Xcode : 7.3 (7D175)
         Git : git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 96d7af9b448bfdb55e1319fac100e08341bb8fab
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.0
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.0.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!

target “MobileShippingApp” do
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

### Error

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `executable' for Pod::Executable:Module
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:111:in `block in which!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:110:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:110:in `which!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:133:in `capture_command'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:101:in `git'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:45:in `block in url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:44:in `chdir'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:44:in `url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:347:in `block in source_with_url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `find'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:346:in `source_with_url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:17:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:654:in `block in sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `map'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:144:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    ```
````

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue, but not through Jenkins though.
I presume that the OS of your system with Jenkins setup is El Capitan.

What I did was, I uninstalled the cocoa pods and installed the latest version of Ruby. 
First, I installed Homebrew.

Homebrew comes with a very simple install script. When it asks you to install XCode CommandLine Tools, say yes.

Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After that I installed Ruby 2.3.1 using rbenv

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1ruby -v
```

After Installing latest version of Ruby, I followed the following steps to install the CocoaPods

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

After gem was successfully installed

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Ruby/bin
```

You can check this issue for more details 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692